# Know of any cool projects done with Parallel Programming and/or the Cell processor?

Tags: cell, parallel-processing, playstation

I've been doing some messing around with the cell processor on the playstation 3 and, having made a few small programs (finding distances between every point in two lists of points ,mandelbrot set generator) I'm looking for something a little bigger to expand my knowledge of the platform. I figured I'd look at what contests for the cell have produced to see if I could find any ideas, but the only one I could find only shows the winners, which all pretty big projects (mapping the human brain, things like that). So, I'm wondering if anybody has any ideas or any projects that they have done to get me started. It doesn't have to be specific to the cell. Most any idea that would involve more than one processor would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

folding@Home is nice are basically any biological/chemical simulators, both fields are full of data that can be processed in parallel, such as DNA parsing, and protein Folding or Drug development. Anyways my point is there is tons of documentation, studies, papers, and needs in those fields. So you might be interested in considering fiddling your way to that.

I worked with DNA simulations back in College.

Answer (score 0):

There the [Crackstation](http://computerworld.co.nz/news.nsf/scrt/C50D36EFEC2B482ACC2573A00070EF83) project from Kiwicon.

Most any embarassingly parallel problem is good on the Cell, one example that comes to mind is the a [Cell specific version](https://www.cgran.org/wiki/GcellizedFFTW) of the FFTW library for the Cell cpu that's used for processing input from the [GNU USRP](http://gnuradio.org/trac/wiki)